# Como realizar um SELECT em duas tabelas diferentes sem alterar nome de colunas?

Tags: sql, ionic

Estou realizando um SELECT em duas tabelas diferentes e unindo elas utilizando UNION para conseguir um único retorno. Porém, o nome da coluna "unidade" está sendo alterado para "alimentos" e não quero que isso aconteça, como resolver isso?

```
public listaMercadoDefaultData(_Method: string, _Tabelas: Array<string>, _Data?: any,) {
    let arrayTabelas: Array<string> = _Tabelas.slice(0);
    if (_Method == 'GET') {
      return this.cDataBaseService.getDB()
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          let sql = `SELECT id, alimentos, tipo FROM ${arrayTabelas[0]} UNION SELECT id, unidade, tipo FROM ${arrayTabelas[1]}`

          return db.executeSql(sql, _Data)
            .then(($return: any) => {
              return $return;
            })
            .catch(($error: any) => {
              console.error($error);
            });
        });
    }
  }
```

Comment: No union vale o nome ou alias do 1° select ... https://jmmwrite.wordpress.com/2009/08/31/diferenca-entre-union-e-join/ ...  o que se quer fazer ?

Answer (score -2):

Para evitar que o nome da coluna "unidade" seja alterado para "alimentos", você pode especificar os nomes das colunas nas duas consultas SELECT que estão sendo unidas. Você pode fazer isso usando o comando AS após o nome da coluna.

Por exemplo:

```
SELECT id, alimentos AS unidade, tipo FROM ${arrayTabelas[0]} 
UNION 
SELECT id, unidade, tipo FROM ${arrayTabelas[1]}
```

Dessa forma, a coluna "unidade" na primeira consulta será renomeada para "unidade" e a coluna "unidade" na segunda consulta será mantida com esse nome. Isso fará com que o resultado final da união das duas consultas tenha uma coluna chamada "unidade" em vez de "alimentos".